Can one check whether a qubit "equals" another with a single copy?
Is it possible to test whether a certain qubit ${\mid}\psi\rangle$ equals, say, ${\mid}\psi_0\rangle = a{\mid}0\rangle + b{\mid}1\rangle$; i.e., can one get a boolean out of ${\mid}\psi\rangle \stackrel{?}{=} {\mid}\psi_0\rangle$?
We're only given a single copy of the qubit ${\mid}\psi\rangle$, which can be destroyed in the operation. Global phases can be ignored.
Note: This answer does not address my question, as I'm not interested in the three-qubit system specified therein.
EDIT: I removed an earlier restriction whereby I didn't want to use ancillary qubits.
EDIT: It seems that we can know for sure if the two qubits are different but we can't know for sure if they're equal. Consider the operation of the following operator
$$
\hat{O} = \begin{bmatrix}
a^* & b^* \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
on $\mid\psi\rangle$. That would return
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
if (and only if?) ${\mid}\psi\rangle = {\mid}\psi_0\rangle$, i.e., the outcome qubit will never project onto the second dimension of the Hilbert space, even with a single shot measurement. Wouldn't this approach hint to a more general solution? (If I may be allowed to spitball, I'm thinking of something along the lines of the Zeno effect, although I haven't worked out the "setup".)

Isnt't this accomplished by just measuring $|\langle\psi|\psi_0\rangle|^2$? You don't get a boolean, but in practice you can implement a threshold and take all values below that as 0 and all values above it as 1.

@paulina I need a boolean. Born's rule only returns probabilities.

answer is no. If it were not no then you could break the no-cloning theorem

@AndrewSteane How is this related to the no-cloning theorem. In other words, how does this question logically require several copies of the qubit?

@paulina You only get a single copy. $\lvert \langle \psi | \psi_0 \rangle \rvert^2$ is a probability that you can't measure with a single copy.

We have
$$
|\psi_0\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle
$$
We then have physical access to one copy of another state
$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle
$$
You are asking how we can compare $|\psi\rangle$ to $|\psi_0\rangle$. Let's consider more generally if we had access to $n$ copies of $|\psi\rangle$.
We cast this as a statistical problem. If we were only interested in estimating $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ then we can just perform $Z$ measurements and record the number of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ recorded. Actually this is the same problem as

Suppose we have an unfair coin that has success probability $p$ for showing up heads. How can we estimate $p$ by flipping the coin $N$ times?

We can then look at the likelihood of our measurement outcome. The measurement outcome will be binomially distributed with success probability $p = |\beta|^2 = 1 - |\alpha|^2$. If $k$ is the number of successes, $n$ is the number of trials, and $p=|\beta|^2$ is the success probability then
$$
P(k, n, p) = \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
For a given experimental run $n$ and $k$ will be fixed and we can think of this probability as a function of $p$. Thought of in this way, $P(k, n, p)$ gives us the likelihood function for $p$. If we select the $\hat{p}$ that maximizes $P(k, n, p)$ then $\hat{p}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator for $p$. With a bit of calculus you can see that
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{k}{n}
$$
as you would naively suspect.
However, we can do better. With more statistics tooling we can even estimate a confidence interval for $p$. There are a few ways to estimate confidence intervals for Binomial success probabilities. One good one is the Wilson score. Suppose we want confidence level $c$, e.g. $c=0.95$ for a 95% confidence interval. We first calculate
$$
z_c = \text{PPF}_Z\left(\frac{1+c}{2}\right)
$$
A sample from a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ will fall within $\mu \pm z_c \sigma$ fraction $c$ of the time. We then calculate the Wilson confidence interval as
$$
\left(\frac{k + \frac{1}{2}z_c^2}{n + z_c^2} - \frac{z_c}{n + z_c^2}\sqrt{\frac{k(n-k)}{n} + \frac{z_c^2}{4}}, \frac{k + \frac{1}{2}z_c^2}{n + z_c^2} + \frac{z_c}{n + z_c^2}\sqrt{\frac{k(n-k)}{n} + \frac{z_c^2}{4}}\right)
$$
As $n$ is increased this confidence interval will get smaller and smaller. However, notably, the confidence interval will never be infinitely small. By increasing $n$ we can get a tighter estimate for $p=|\beta^2|$ but we'll never know with complete certainty.

Ok, with this statistical machinery under our belt we can answer the OP. The point is that with repeated trials we can estimate $|\beta|^2$ with some confidence interval. We can compare this to $|b|^2$ to report something like how confident we are that $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\psi_0\rangle$ are equal. However, as $n$ gets smaller the error bars are going to get so large that the estimate is basically useless. Also, at small $n$ the error bars will likely be very inaccurate. That is, calculated analytically as shown above, I think it is unlikely the confidence intervals will actually contain the true value fraction $c$ of trials of the experiment as they should for accurate confidence intervals.
The short answer is going to be: No, you cannot reliably determine if $|\psi\rangle$ is equal (or even close to $|\psi_0\rangle$) with access to only one physical copy of $|\psi\rangle$.

Note in the question you were only asking about comparing the populations of the two states and ignoring the phase. In this case the problem reduces to the statistics of flipping a coin. This is pretty easy to understand and a great pedagogical example for learning about maximum likelihood estimation and confidence intervals. However, the problem would be tractable even if you cared about the phase as well. In this case you could do X measurements in addition to Z measurements. Between all the measurements you would get information about the magnitude of $\beta$ and also the phase of $\beta$ relative to that of $\alpha$. You could then construct a similar likelihood function for these two parameters jointly and construct maximum likelihood estimates and a confidence region or confidence intervals for the estimates.

But the best measurement won't be in the computational basis?

@NorbertSchuch For just estimating $|\beta|^2$ I would be shocked if just measuring $Z$ isn't the right thing to do. For measuring amplitude and phase... I'm not a state tomography guy so I don't know what is the "optimal" usage of resources here. If I was asked to do this I would probably use half my measurements to measure the $Z$ basis and half the measurements either to measure in the $X$ basis or to do some sort of Ramsey to estimate the phase.

@Jagerber48 perhaps put the part where the question is answered in bold or otherwise add some visual guide to that part. It would also be helpful to explicitly write down the confidence interval in the case $n=1$ and explain the Bayesian inference going on in that case.

@DanielSank thanks for your suggestions. I'll work to improve the organization. I can try to write down the Wilson score confidence interval for $n=1$. I'm a little reticent to even write it down though because I'm suspicious in that case the interval is not valid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Validity). I'm not sure what you mean about the "Bayesian inference" so not sure I can include that.

@Jagerber48 It depends a bit what you mean precisely, but, say, if you know that the amplitudes are positive (or real), i.e. the state is $\cos(\phi)\lvert0\rangle + \sin(\phi)\lvert1\rangle$, it is clear by symmetry that a $Z$ measurement can't be always optimal, since all directions in the X-Z-plane (in particular, X and Z axis measurements) are interchangable here. For the first measurements, it will not matter, and if you have already collected information, you want to do measurements from which you learn the most (i.e. with the largest fluctuations).

If you are interested in how to measure the overlap $| \langle \psi | \psi _0 \rangle |^2$ using multiple copies within a quantum circuit, take a look at this SE post (SWAP test).
A single qubit-state $|\psi (c,d) \rangle = c | 0 \rangle  + d | 1 \rangle$ is fully characterized by a single variable $\alpha$ because of the normalization condition $|c|^2 + |d|^2 = 1$ which eliminates one variable and you end up with $| \psi (\alpha)\rangle$. So your question can be formulated as "how can I check if $\alpha = \beta$ by performing a single measurement on the state $| \psi (\alpha)\rangle$?"
The reason you get a single measurement if you only start with a single qubit in the state $|\psi (\alpha ) \rangle$ is two-fold:

Due to the  no-cloning theorem you cannot make copies of the unknown state $| \psi (\alpha)\rangle$.
If you perform a measurement on $| \psi (\alpha)\rangle$ in any basis $\{ |\tilde{0} \rangle, | \tilde{1} \rangle \}$, you will collapse the superposition
$$
|\psi (\tilde{c},\tilde{d}) \rangle = \tilde{c} | \tilde{0} \rangle  + \tilde{d} | \tilde{1} \rangle
$$
either onto $ |\tilde{0} \rangle$ or $ | \tilde{1} \rangle$ and thus change $\alpha \to \alpha^\prime$, where both $\alpha$'s are unknown. (You may have $|\tilde{0} \rangle = |\psi_{0} \rangle$). Measurements are not unitary and thus not reversible.

Because you specified not to be interested in using ancilla qubits and multiple copies of the state (for that see the SWAP test), the immediate answer is that this is not possible. To demonstrate that this is not possible, we first consider the two states
$$
|\phi_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} | 0 \rangle + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} | 1 \rangle ,
\qquad
|\phi_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( | 0 \rangle  + | 1 \rangle \big) ,
$$
and perform a measurement in the $\{ |0 \rangle, | 1 \rangle \}$ basis. (Equivalently you can measure it in any basis you like). Then, in your first and only measurement you measure both states to be in the $| 1 \rangle $ state and you are left with
$$
|\phi_1 \rangle \xrightarrow{\text{measurement}} | 1 \rangle ,
\qquad
|\phi_2 \rangle \xrightarrow{\text{measurement}} | 1 \rangle .
$$
From this single measurement you can't even decipher if you have started with two different states $|\phi_1 \rangle \neq |\phi_2 \rangle$. You may even start with two equal states $|\phi_1 \rangle = |\phi_2 \rangle$ and a single measurement on the two states may give you
$$
|\phi_1 \rangle \xrightarrow{\text{measurement}} | 1 \rangle ,
\qquad
|\phi_2 \rangle \xrightarrow{\text{measurement}} | 0 \rangle .
$$
Clearly, you cannot conclude that these two states are different, because we started with two identical states pre-measurement.
In summary, you cannot check whether one qubit $|\psi (\alpha) \rangle$ is equals to $|\psi (\beta) \rangle$ with a single copy. This is because the state $|\psi (\alpha) \rangle$ can only be measured once before the state is changed. (Measurements are irreverisble and the no-cloning theorem). From this we can only conclude that the weight on this basis state is non-zero, but gain no more information than that, as demonstrated by the examples above.

I've lifted the restriction on not having ancillary qubits in the OP. Would that help in coming up with an answer?

@Tfovid Having ancillas should not change the answer, because you are trying to measure a probability distribution with a single copy. On that note, could you please not delete assumptions from your question that both current answers used? (Maybe make an edit with "EDIT: ..." to add the other scenario). Now our answers are suddenly somewhat decoupled from your question.
